# Angular 1.x filter - modifying filtered elements affects original array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

**Background info**

A tour agency has tours departing every day. In each of these tours there are a varying amount of groups - different vehicles for the same tour departure run on the same day at the same time.

For the management system that lists all tours that are scheduled, I'm building a filter that can do two things:

1) If any of the checkboxes for filtering days is selected (Mon, Tue, Wed etc), only tours that run on those selected days will show.

2) If any checkboxes for filtering groups (1st group, 2nd group, 3rd group etc) is checked, then only those groups will show. For example: if a tour only has 1 group and the checkbox for the 2nd group is checked, then this group will not show. If a tour has three groups, and the same same checkbox for he 2nd group is checked, then only the second group will show.

**The problem**

The day filter part works perfectly fine. The group order part of the filter doesn't. In the filter, whenever I remove a group from the `groups` object within the `filteredDepartures` array, it affects the original `departures` array. Whenever I select the first group order filter checkbox, all groups but the first ones disappear, but when I deselect the same checkbox, the groups don't reappear, as they have effectively been removed from the original `departures` array.

Here's my filter code:

```
app.filter('departuresFilter', function() { //Filter departures
    return function(departures, filterOptions) {

        if (typeof departures !== 'undefined') //If there are departures
        {
            var filteredDepartures = []; //Create new array

            //See if days should be filtered
            filterOptions.daysFiltered = false; //Assuming days won't be filtered
            filterOptions.days.forEach(function(day) {
                if (day.selected) //Day is selected
                    filterOptions.daysFiltered = true;
            });

            //See if group orders should be filtered
            //The array groupsInDepartures is an array that has as many elements as the highest amount of groups on any day within selected date range (typically 1-3 elements)
            filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = false; //Assuming group orders won't be filtered
            filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups.forEach(function (group) { //For every group order.
                if (group.selected) //A checkbox has been selected
                    filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = true;
            }); 

            for (i = 0; i < departures.length; i++) //For every tour departure
            {
                var removeDeparture = false; //Assuming departure will not be removed

                if (filterOptions.daysFiltered) //Days are filtered
                {
                    filterOptions.days.forEach(function(day) { //For every day in filter array
                        if (day.title == departures[i].date.D) //Found this group's day in day filter array
                        {
                            if (day.selected == false) //This day is not selected (should not show)
                                removeDeparture = true; //Remove day
                        }
                    });
                }

                //Departure is not to be removed - check if any groups should be removed
                if (removeDeparture == false)
                {
                    filteredDepartures.push(departures[i]); //Add departure to filtered departures array

                    if (filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered) //Group orders should be filtered. Only show groups of which their corresponding checkbox has been selected.
                    {
                        var departureIndex = filteredDepartures.length - 1; //Get index for last departure

                        for (j = filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.length; j > 0; j--) //For every group in departure. Start from above, to not mess up indexes.
                        {
                            if (!filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups[j - 1].selected) //This group should be removed
                                filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.splice((j - 1), 1); //Remove group
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return filteredDepartures;
        }
    };
});
```

So this part is the problem, since it not only removes the group from the `filteredDepartures` array, but also from the `departures` array:

```
if (!filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups[j - 1].selected) //This group should be removed
    filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.splice((j - 1), 1); //Remove group
```

I've also tried JSON-stingifying the `departures` array and then creating an all new object in the filter, to remove any reference to the original array, but Angular gives me an error message about too many cycles.

**EDIT**

Posting HTML as well. The first table is for selecting dates, and for filtering days and groups (size type filtering not yet active). Second table is for generating the tour departures list.

```
<table style="margin: 40px 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Dates</h2>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 40px;">
            <h2>Filter groups</h2>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 40px;">
            <h2>Filters applied</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <ul class="cleanList">
                <li>From <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateStart" style="width: 120px; text-align: center;" ng-change="loadGroups()" jqdatepicker></li>
                <li>To<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateEnd" style="width: 120px; text-align: center;" ng-change="loadGroups()" jqdatepicker></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 40px; vertical-align: top;">
            Size Type
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="filterOptions.sizeType">
                <option></option>
                <option ng-repeat="sizeType in groupSizeTypes" value="{{ sizeType.id }}">{{ sizeType.title }}</option>
            </select>

            <ul class="horList">
                <li ng-repeat="day in filterOptions.days">
                    <div><label for="{{ day.title }}">{{ day.title }}</label></div>
                    <div style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="{{ day.title }}" ng-model="day.selected"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div ng-show="filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups.length > 0">
                Groups
                <ul class="horList">
                    <li ng-repeat="group in filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups">
                        <div><label for="nth_group_{{ group.order }}">{{ group.order }}</label></div>
                        <div style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="nth_group_{{ group.order }}" ng-model="group.selected"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 40px; vertical-align: top;" ng-show="filterOptions.tag != '' || filterOptions.daysFiltered || filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered">
            <ul>
                <li ng-show="filterOptions.tag != ''">Tag</li>
                <li ng-show="filterOptions.daysFiltered">Days</li>
                <li ng-show="filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered">Groups</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{ departures }} <!-- for debugging (filtering groups from filteredDepartures removes them from this array as well) -->

<p id="loadWrap" style="display: none;"><span class="loadBox"><img src="/images/misc/ajax-loader.gif">Loading</span></p>
<p ng-show="filteredDepartures.length" class="small"><i>Showing {{ filteredDepartures.length }} departures.</i></p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Tour</th>
        <th>Size type</th>
        <th>Pax</th>
        <th>Guide</th>
        <th>Salary K CLP</th>
        <th>Vehicle</th>
        <th>Rental K CLP</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="departure in filteredDepartures = (departures | departuresFilter:filterOptions)">
        <tr class="danger">
            <td><a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="loadThisDate(departure.date.Ymd)">{{ departure.date.Mj }}</a><div class="small" style="color: gray;">{{ departure.date.D }}</div></td>
            <td>{{ departure.tour.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ departure.tour.sizeType.title }}</td>
            <td colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="group in departure.groups" class="trNoTopBorder danger">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>{{ group.pax }} / {{ group.capacity }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.guide.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.salaryKCLP }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.vehicle.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.vehicleRentalKCLP }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid using filter on angularjs, because it calls again and again. Use directive as possible as, because directive is cheapest.

Secondly, if you want to clone a javascript object you should use **angular.copy**  On **`filteredDepartures.push(departures[i])`** you are push original item, it is not cloned. Use `filteredDepartures.push(angular.copy(departures[i]));`

Also if filterOptions is static, namely not changaable you can $watch only departures;

```
app.directive('departuresDirective', function () { 
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            var filterOptions, departures;
            scope.filteredDepartures = [];
            scope.$watchGroup([attr.filterOptions, attr.departures], function (newValues, oldValues, scope) {
                filterOptions = newValues[0];
                departures = newValues[1];
                scope.filteredDepartures =  filterDepartures(departures, filterOptions);
            }, true);

            function filterDepartures(departures, filterOptions) {
                if (typeof departures !== 'undefined') //If there are departures
                {
                    var filteredDepartures = []; //Create new array

                    //See if days should be filtered
                    filterOptions.daysFiltered = false; //Assuming days won't be filtered
                    filterOptions.days.forEach(function (day) {
                        if (day.selected) //Day is selected
                            filterOptions.daysFiltered = true;
                    });

                    //See if group orders should be filtered
                    //The array groupsInDepartures is an array that has as many elements as the highest amount of groups on any day within selected date range (typically 1-3 elements)
                    filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = false; //Assuming group orders won't be filtered
                    filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups.forEach(function (group) { //For every group order.
                        if (group.selected) //A checkbox has been selected
                            filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = true;
                    });

                    for (i = 0; i < departures.length; i++) //For every tour departure
                    {
                        var removeDeparture = false; //Assuming departure will not be removed

                        if (filterOptions.daysFiltered) //Days are filtered
                        {
                            filterOptions.days.forEach(function (day) { //For every day in filter array
                                if (day.title == departures[i].date.D) //Found this group's day in day filter array
                                {
                                    if (day.selected == false) //This day is not selected (should not show)
                                        removeDeparture = true; //Remove day
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        //Departure is not to be removed - check if any groups should be removed
                        if (removeDeparture == false) {
                            filteredDepartures.push(angular.copy(departures[i])); //Add departure to filtered departures array

                            if (filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered) //Group orders should be filtered. Only show groups of which their corresponding checkbox has been selected.
                            {
                                var departureIndex = filteredDepartures.length - 1; //Get index for last departure

                                for (j = filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.length; j >= 0; j--) //For every group in departure. Start from above, to not mess up indexes.
                                {
                                    if (!filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups[j - 1].selected) //This group should be removed
                                        filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.splice((j - 1), 1); //Remove group
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return filteredDepartures;
                }
            }

        }
    };
});
```

## html for directive

```
    <table class="table" departures-directive="" departures="departures"  filter-options="filterOptions">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Tour</th>
        <th>Size type</th>
        <th>Pax</th>
        <th>Guide</th>
        <th>Salary K CLP</th>
        <th>Vehicle</th>
        <th>Rental K CLP</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="departure in filteredDepartures track by $index">
        <tr class="danger">
            <td><a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="loadThisDate(departure.date.Ymd)">{{ departure.date.Mj }}</a><div class="small" style="color: gray;">{{ departure.date.D }}</div></td>
            <td>{{ departure.tour.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ departure.tour.sizeType.title }}</td>
            <td colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="group in departure.groups track by $index" class="trNoTopBorder danger">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>{{ group.pax }} / {{ group.capacity }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.guide.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.salaryKCLP }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.vehicle.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ group.vehicleRentalKCLP }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## edit filter

```
app.filter('departuresFilter', function() { //Filter departures
    return function(_departures, _filterOptions) {
         var departures = angular.copy(_departures);
         var filterOptions = angular.copy(_filterOptions);
        if (typeof departures !== 'undefined') //If there are departures
        {
            var filteredDepartures = []; //Create new array

            //See if days should be filtered
            filterOptions.daysFiltered = false; //Assuming days won't be filtered
            filterOptions.days.forEach(function(day) {
                if (day.selected) //Day is selected
                    filterOptions.daysFiltered = true;
            });

            //See if group orders should be filtered
            //The array groupsInDepartures is an array that has as many elements as the highest amount of groups on any day within selected date range (typically 1-3 elements)
            filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = false; //Assuming group orders won't be filtered
            filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups.forEach(function (group) { //For every group order.
                if (group.selected) //A checkbox has been selected
                    filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = true;
            }); 

            for (i = 0; i < departures.length; i++) //For every tour departure
            {
                var removeDeparture = false; //Assuming departure will not be removed

                if (filterOptions.daysFiltered) //Days are filtered
                {
                    filterOptions.days.forEach(function(day) { //For every day in filter array
                        if (day.title == departures[i].date.D) //Found this group's day in day filter array
                        {
                            if (day.selected == false) //This day is not selected (should not show)
                                removeDeparture = true; //Remove day
                        }
                    });
                }

                //Departure is not to be removed - check if any groups should be removed
                if (removeDeparture == false)
                {
                    filteredDepartures.push(departures[i]); //Add departure to filtered departures array

                    if (filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered) //Group orders should be filtered. Only show groups of which their corresponding checkbox has been selected.
                    {
                        var departureIndex = filteredDepartures.length - 1; //Get index for last departure

                        for (j = filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.length; j >= 0; j--) //For every group in departure. Start from above, to not mess up indexes.
                        {
                            if (!filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups[j - 1].selected) //This group should be removed
                                filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.splice((j - 1), 1); //Remove group
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return filteredDepartures;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, I'll look into the directives! I'm not sure how to use them in the HTML, but I'll look it up. When I use angular.copy I get the same error as when creating a new object with JSON stringify and parse: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig. I tried it at the line `filteredDepartures.push(angular.copy(departures[i]));` as well as copying the whole array in the beginning of it all. Still the same error. Any clues?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Also Why you try to remove the gruop from array? Just use ng-if or ng-hide directives to show or hide a checkbox or group. You can filter results when you save or on back-end.

Comment: HTML posted. Since it was possible to filter the days just fine, I wanted to do the same with the groups for a cleaner solution. If not possible, I'll do what you suggest!

Comment: Can you try the directive I wrote? It is possible that filter result so many $diggest cycle. Also you should fix  for (j = filteredDepartures[departureIndex].groups.length; j => 0; j--)  on your filter code.

Comment: Also don't forget using  track by $index on repeaters. If repeted item have an unique id, use it instead of $index

Comment: I used the directive fix - there are no errors, but the page is idle. When I click the filter options (filter by day, or by group order), nothing happens. How can I connect the controls to the directive? Though, I think we're close to a solution! With the filter method, simply by adding `track by $index`, it suddenly works! The original array remains intact, BUT I still get `Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop` caused by `filteredDepartures.push(departures[i]);`. The problem probably lies in nesting an ng-repeated `<tr>` inside an ng-repeated `<tbody>`.

Comment: Actulay, If I were you, I will write a clear component which have some method, like filterDay, filterGroup etc. It seems that there is a circular operation in your filter code. You are changing values of filter options by click, also in your filtering code you are changing filterOptions value again. Thus the code working in endless loop. Try copy *departures* and *filterOptions* on begining of the filter function. I edited for you. Or write a  simple and clear component. Avoid from comlexity, beause angular has dirty check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mehmet Otkun's guidance, to avoid Angular's dirty filter checks, I ended up writing a function `$scope.filterDepartures()`. On every select box and checkbox I added a `ng-change="filterDepartures()"`. The code for the function is basically exactly the same. This version is a bit longer though, since I've been developing it some more during the day. An essential detail is using `angular.copy()` though, to lose all references to original object.

Here's the function:

```
$scope.filterDepartures = function() { //Filter departures
    $scope.filteredDepartures = []; //Create new array
    $scope.groupCount = 0; //Reset group count var
    $scope.filterOptions.largestGroup = 0; //Var for remembering biggest group. This is for creating capacity array for editing groups.

    //See if days should be filtered
    $scope.filterOptions.daysFiltered = false; //Assuming days won't be filtered
    $scope.filterOptions.days.forEach(function(day) {
        if (day.selected) //Day is selected
            $scope.filterOptions.daysFiltered = true;
    });

    //See if group orders should be filtered
    //The array groupsInDepartures is an array that has as many elements as the highest amount of groups on any day within selected date range (typically 1-3 elements)
    $scope.filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = false; //Assuming group orders won't be filtered
    $scope.filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups.forEach(function (group) { //For every group order.
        if (group.selected) //A checkbox has been selected
            $scope.filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered = true;
    }); 

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.departures.length; i++) //For every tour departure
    {
        var removeDeparture = false; //Assuming departure will not be removed

        if ($scope.filterOptions.daysFiltered) //Days are filtered
        {
            $scope.filterOptions.days.forEach(function(day) { //For every day in filter array
                if (day.title == $scope.departures[i].date.D) //Found this group's day in day filter array
                {
                    if (day.selected == false) //This day is not selected (should not show)
                        removeDeparture = true; //Remove day
                }
            });
        }

        //Departure is not to be removed - check if any groups should be removed
        if (removeDeparture == false)
        {
            var tempDeparture = angular.copy($scope.departures[i]); //Create temporary departure object

            for (j = (tempDeparture.groups.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) //For every group in departure. Start from above, to not mess up indexes.
            {
                var removeGroup = false; //Assuming group shouldn't be removed

                if ($scope.filterOptions.groupOrdersFiltered && !$scope.filterOptions.groupsInDepartures.groups[j].selected) //Group orders should be filtered. Only show groups of which their corresponding checkbox has been selected.
                    removeGroup = true; //Remove group later
                else //Continue checking
                {
                    //Check if guide is filtered, and if this group has the correct guide
                    if ($scope.filterOptions.guide.exists && $scope.filterOptions.guide.id != tempDeparture.groups[j].guide.id)
                        removeGroup = true;
                    else //Guide was not filtered. Continue checking
                    {
                        //Check if vehicle is filtered, and if this group has the correct vehicle
                        if ($scope.filterOptions.vehicle.exists && $scope.filterOptions.vehicle.id != tempDeparture.groups[j].vehicle.id)
                            removeGroup = true;
                    }
                }


                if (removeGroup) //Group should be removed
                    tempDeparture.groups.splice((j), 1); //Remove group
            }

            //Loop through all groups that are left, looking for largest group
            tempDeparture.groups.forEach(function (group) {
                if (group.pax > $scope.filterOptions.largestGroup) //Found bigger group
                    $scope.filterOptions.largestGroup = group.pax; //Save to var
            });

            $scope.groupCount += tempDeparture.groups.length;

            if (!$scope.filterOptions.hideGrouplessDepartures || $scope.filterOptions.hideGrouplessDepartures && tempDeparture.groups.length > 0)
                $scope.filteredDepartures.push(tempDeparture); //Add departure to filtered departures array
        }
    }

    $scope.capEditGroupsOptions = [];
    //Renew array for editing group capacity, to let user limit capacity to the same amount of pax as the most amount of pax in any of the groups that are shown
    for (i = $scope.filterOptions.largestGroup; i <= <?php echo $maxCapacity; ?>; i++) //For every capacity option possible
    {
        $scope.capEditGroupsOptions.push(i);
    }
};
```

I'm still not sure why it didn't work using a filter. My only thought is that it's a bug in Angular. There has been a huge amounts of improvements since Angular 1.x. Using a function that's only executed when I tell it to, which generates a filtered array, is better in any way though, and is definitely what I'll do in the future.